# PHP Session auto expires after certain time

Tags: php, session

I have one login page. When the user logs in I will set the session according to user_id but it auto logs out to the user even if the user has not logs out. The session variable get auto expired.

The session auto expires after certain time. What to do on this?? I have set:

```
session.gc_lifetime=7200 and session.cookie_lifetime=0.
```

Any answers will be very helpful?

Comment: What you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in
>   seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the
>   browser is closed.

More importantly, the first variable is misspelled, it has to be `session.gc_maxlifetime`, sou you are using the default exprire time of 24 minutes ...